# Get data based on repetitive group values

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, sql-server-2017

I have no idea how to name the question properly, but here is sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_data
(
    row_version     VARBINARY(8)
  , account_number  CHAR(8)
  , account_balance DECIMAL(10, 2)
  , group_rank      BIGINT
  , rownum          BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO dbo.test_data
VALUES (0x000000000013fd24, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 86)
     , (0x000000000013fd23, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 86)
     , (0x000000000013fd22, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 85)
     , (0x000000000013fd21, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 85)
     , (0x000000000013fd20, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 83)
     , (0x000000000013fd1f, '46436663', 555.00, 2, 83)
     , (0x000000000013fd21, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 85)
     , (0x000000000013fd20, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 83)
     , (0x000000000013fd21, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 85)
     , (0x000000000013fd20, '46436663', 123.00, 4, 83)
     , (0x000000000013fd1e, '46436664', 12345.00, 5, 82)
     , (0x000000000013fd1d, '46436664', 12345.00, 5, 82)
     , (0x000000000013fd1c, '46436664', 12345.00, 5, 82)
     , (0x000000000013fd1b, '46436664', 12345.00, 5, 81)
     , (0x000000000013fd1a, '46436664', 12345.00, 5, 81)
     , (0x000000000013fd19, '46436664', 12345.00, 5, 78)
     , (0x000000000013fcb3, '46436664', 123.00, 6, 77)
     , (0x000000000013fcb2, '46436664', 123.00, 6, 77)
     , (0x000000000013fcb1, '46436664', 123.00, 6, 76)
     , (0x000000000013fcb0, '46436664', 123.00, 6, 76);
```

This is how data look like:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.test_data
ORDER BY row_version DESC
```

[image]

Here 1 and 4 (blue) are sequential group numbers, that have minimum sequence of 2 the same values in a roll of you order them by `row_version`. I need to find first occurrence of different `group_rank` (2, red) and then check `rownum` value (3,6, purple) where it is `MIN(row_num)` for upper group (blue) and `row_num` for the record that comes just before the group ended (red). If these values differs by 1, then I need to the `account_number` then I need to return it, otherwise - I don't need to return it.

I'm not interested in what happened below 2 and 5 points (red) for the accounts.

So, by looking to that data, the only account should be returned - `46436664` as for `46436663` `rownum` value is the same (83).

Comment: So, what are the results you are after here exactly?

Comment: I didn't fit get you. If you are talking about expected result, then it is 46436664

Comment: So your expect result is *just* the value `46436664`? Nothing else?

Comment: Yes, just single

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem I guess the first step is finding the problem account_numbers, which you could do like this.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    dbo.test_data t1
cross apply (
    select top 1 
        * 
    from 
        dbo.test_data 
    where 
        account_number = t1.account_number
        and rownum = t1.rownum
        and row_version > t1.row_version 
    order by 
        row_version asc) t2
where 
    t1.group_rank <> t2.group_rank 
order by
    t1.row_version;
```

[image]

Then you could do this

```
select distinct 
    t0.account_number 
from 
    test_data t0

except

select distinct
    t1.account_number 
from 
    dbo.test_data t1
cross apply (
    select top 1 
        * 
    from 
        dbo.test_data 
    where 
        account_number = t1.account_number
        and rownum = t1.rownum
        and row_version > t1.row_version 
    order by 
        row_version asc) t2
where 
    t1.group_rank <> t2.group_rank
```